# Get a certain value from a concatenated table

Tags: lua

Trying to allow a concatenated table to be referenced as such:

```
local group = table.concat(arguments, ",", 1)
```

where arguments = {"1,1,1"}

Currently, doing `group[2]` gives me the comma. How do I avoid that while still allowing for two-digit numbers?

(snippet of what I'm trying to use it for)

`for i = 1, #group do
target:SetGroup(i, tonumber(group[i]))
end`

Comment: `table.concat` turns a table into a string. If `arguments` is a table of one string `table.concat` isn't going to do anything particularly meaningful for you.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want something like

```
local i = 1
for v in string.gmatch(s, "(%w+),*") do
   group[i] = v
   i = i + 1
end
```

Revised version in response to comment, avoiding the table altogether:

```
local i = 1
for v in string.gmatch(s, "(%w+),*") do
   target:SetGroup(i, tonumber(v))
   i = i + 1
end
```

Comment: I wanted the target:SetGroup feature to run as many times as there are numbers (if it's "1,1,1", run 3 times, each time the first "i" in setgroup is changing from 1 to 2 to 3). It would also use the numbers from the supplied table. How would I implement this?

Comment: The code I provided creates the table from the string. The code in your question should work fine with the `group` table it builds. Or you could avoid tables altogether with the revised version.

Answer (score 0):

split function (you have to add it to code)

```
split = function(str, delim)
    if not delim then
        delim = " "
    end
    -- Eliminate bad cases...
    if string.find(str, delim) == nil then
        return { str }
    end
    local result = {}
    local pat = "(.-)" .. delim .. "()"
    local nb = 0
    local lastPos
    for part, pos in string.gfind(str, pat) do
        nb = nb + 1
        result[nb] = part
        lastPos = pos
    end
    -- Handle the last field
    result[nb + 1] = string.sub(str, lastPos)
    return result
end
```

so

```
local arguments = {"1,1,1"};
local group = split(arguments[1], ",");

for i = 1, #group do
    target:SetGroup(i, tonumber(group[i]))
end
```

<s>also note that</s>

```
local arguments = {"1,1,1"};
local group = split(arguments[1], ",");
local group_count = #group;

for i = 1, group_count do
    target:SetGroup(i, tonumber(group[i]))
end
```

is faster code ;)

Comment: The second version isn't faster code. It could even be slightly slower because it has an extra assignment to a local variable (and there is more code to parse/compile) ...